# Accessing an Object's properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Hello I am doing a school assignment my main problem is as follows.

```
var objectQueue = {
                customers:[
                {name:"Phil", order:"coffee"},
                {name:"Sandy", order:"coffee"},
                {name:"Enrique", order:"sandwich"},
                {name:"Joe", order:"coffee"},
                {name:"Alex", order:"muffin"},
                {name:"Zoe", order:"chili"},
                {name:"Bahamut", order:"sandwich"},
                {name:"Rydia", order:"timbits"}
            ]
        };
```

I have this object, I need to know how to access each customer's order through a for loop. I can't get the loop to read each person's order. What would be the right way to do this?

This is where I am currently:

```
objectQueue[x]order
```

Comment: Dude, come on. That is not even trying.

Comment: We don't generate code here. We fix it. Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: I didn't need the whole loop, just the way to access the different parts of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `x` is a counter:

```
objectQueue.customers[x].order
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to access the length of the customers and use that as your loop count, from there you can use 'i' your counter to access properties

```
for (i=0; i<objectQueue.customers.length; i++){
     console.log(objectQueue.customers[i]);
     console.log(objectQueue.customers[i].name);
     console.log(objectQueue.customers[i].order);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`objectQueue` has a property named `customers`, to access a simple property on a Javascript object, you can just use its name:
`objectQueue.customers`

Then, `customers` has a `array` of objects.  To access elements in a array, we use its index:

`customers[0]`

Since the elements in the list are maps/objects, we can access them via properties as well:

`customers[0].name`

Putting this all together we get:

`objectQueue.customers[0].name`

Almost everything in Javascript is an object, so it's a little misleading to differentiate between arrays and objects (since arrays ARE objects), but I'm assuming you can dig into those details later if you're interested.  In the meantime, this should get you going.